# Eclipse getting crashed after throwing "Throwable during asyncExec Malformed class name"

Tags: java, eclipse

My Eclipse workbench is getting closed after throwing error:

```
Throwable during asyncExec
Malformed class name
```

Attched are the screenshots as well.

[image]

[image]

Below is the error

```
!ENTRY org.scala-ide.sdt.core 4 0 2018-04-21 12:10:18.717
!MESSAGE Throwable during asyncExec
!STACK 0
java.lang.InternalError: Malformed class name
at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.isAnonymousClass(Unknown Source)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.logging.log4j.Log4JFacade$Logger$.apply(Log4JFacade.scala:60)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.logging.log4j.Log4JFacade.getLogger(Log4JFacade.scala:68)
at org.scalaide.logging.HasLogger.logger(HasLogger.scala:19)
at org.scalaide.logging.HasLogger.logger$(HasLogger.scala:17)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector.logger$lzycompute(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:17)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector.logger(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:17)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector.getClassSafe(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:82)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector.RunWithAnnotationOpt$lzycompute(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:74)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector.RunWithAnnotationOpt(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:74)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector$JUnit4TestClassesTraverser.hasRunWithAnnotation(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:59)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector$JUnit4TestClassesTraverser.isTestClass(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:57)
at org.scalaide.core.internal.launching.JUnit4TestClassesCollector$JUnit4TestClassesTraverser.$anonfun$isRunnableTestClass$1(JUnit4TestClassesCollector.scala:44)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcZ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcZ$sp.java:12)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.InterruptReq.execute(InterruptReq.scala:26)
at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global.$anonfun$pollForWork$1(Global.scala:444)
at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.Global.pollForWork(Global.scala:418)
at scala.tools.nsc.interactive.PresentationCompilerThread.run(PresentationCompilerThread.scala:22)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: the issue is with the Maven. While removing the maven perspective the IDE is working fine.

Comment: Hello. Were you able to get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue using  eclipse scala-IDE with maven. It happens when u have a case class .
https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/2034

Copy the case class and put that inside the scala object class(like an inner class), do not keep it outside of the object class.

Or Switch to intellij, these are the only solutions as per my knowledge